# Is there a best practice for storing data from a websocket?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, sqlalchemy, real-time

I'm currently trying to listen to a web socket which provides hundreds of messages per second. I would like to store the data for further analysis, however, while the storing process is running I can't listen for any new incoming messages (data). This will inevitably lead to data loss, which I'd like to prevent.

I'm using python for that and sqlalchemy for the data storing part.

```
import websocket
import json
import time


w_socket = 'wss://ws.sorare.com/cable'
identifier = json.dumps({"channel": "GraphqlChannel"})

subscription_query = {
  "query": "subscription onAnyCardUpdated { aCardWasUpdated { slug } }",
  "variables": {},
  "operationName": "onAnyCardUpdated",
  "action": "execute"
}

def on_open(ws):
  subscribe_command = {"command": "subscribe", "identifier": identifier}
  ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_command).encode())

  time.sleep(1)

  message_command = {
    "command": "message",
    "identifier": identifier,
    "data": json.dumps(subscription_query)
  }
  ws.send(json.dumps(message_command).encode())

def on_message(ws, data):
  message = json.loads(data)
  type = message.get('type')
  if type == 'welcome':
    pass
  elif type == 'ping':
    pass
  elif message.get('message') is not None:
    print(message['message'])

def on_error(ws, error):
  print('Error:', error)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_message):
  print('WebSocket Closed:', close_message, close_status_code)

def long_connection():
  ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
    w_socket,
    on_message=on_message,
    on_close=on_close,
    on_error=on_error,
    on_open=on_open
  )
  ws.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  long_connection()
´´´
```

Comment: `while the storing process is running I can't listen for any new incoming messages (data` any robust WebSocket implementation provides buffering. If you cannot write faster than you buffer, there is no way you could write the data fast enough in the first place.